# What are the rules for playing Four way Chess

Tags: chess, variants

In 4 way chess on what square do pawns get promoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.chess.com/4-player-chess

It's a point-based system where you get points for a variety of events, including: capturing pieces of the other three players, putting multiple kings in check with a single move, and accepting the resignation of the only remaining player.

Comment: Are there different rules for how pieces move and pawn promotion, and is it just a free for all?

Comment: The video explicitly lists one difference for promotion (or similarity, if you think of it in terms of being the 8th rank...)